# update to httr 1.4.7 and curl 5.0.2 package is causing authentication issue

Tags: r, curl, httr

I have a script that uses `httr` package for GET and POST.
The script used to work without any issues for years (since 2019). but recently after updating httr package (with curl 5.0.2) to 1.4.7, the `GET` is resulting in code 401. `POST` is working fine.

I believe this is due to something in R specifically httr 1.4.7, I tried the same url, headers, and credentials with python `requests` package and it works there. I also tried command line curl and it worked, then I tried `system(curl)` command in R, which is same as command line curl and it still works.

It just does not work with the code below. I will have to post this code to Posit Connect server where its being used by several applications to fetch data.

Can someone please confirm the issue is with updates to curl/httr? And how this can be fixed?

```
r = POST(
    url = paste(apiUrl, "auth/login", sep = ""),
    use_proxy("http://proxy-xyz.pqr.com", 9090, "pxy-uid", "pxy-pwd"),
    add_headers(Accept = "application/vnd.seeq.v1+json",
                `Content-Type` = "application/vnd.seeq.v1+json"),
    body = paste('{"authProviderClass":"Auth",
                   "authProviderId":"Vendor",
                   "username":"uid",
                   "password":"pwd"}',sep = "")
                 )
                              
token <<- r[["headers"]][["x-sq-auth"]]
```

```
r = GET(url = "https://myurl",
        use_proxy("https://proxy-xyz.pqur.com", 9090, "pxy-uid", "pxy-pwd"),
        query = list(start = start, end = end, period = period),
        add_headers(Accept = "application/vnd.seeq.v1+json",
                    `x-sq-auth` = token
                    #`x-sq-csrf` = token
                    )
        )
fromJSON(content(r, as="text", encoding="UTF-8"))[["samples"]]
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is the proxy declaration essential to the issue? I.e. can you try it without the proxy to confirm that this causes the issue?

Comment: proxy declaration is not necessary on my machine but for Posit-Connect server, I believe it is. I did try without the proxy, the POST still works without proxy but GET still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know a whole lot about curl other than I can use it for `GET` and `POST` from API's.
I found out that `GET` worked for me after I do `httr::reset_config` and restarted the R session.

I realized that What actually was happening, that when I ran `GET` without running the `POST` (manually adding the token, obtained by running `POST` previously), it worked but it failed when I ran `POST` first and then `GET`.

I found that when I run `POST`, it sets some cookies! and the cookies have two different authentication tokens `x-sq-auth` and `x-sq-csrf`.

So If I use only `x-sq-auth` token after running `POST`, I am getting an 401 authentication error.

After running `POST` I have to use `x-sq-csrf` token in my `GET` request. This solved my issue but I am not sure why it works this way.

I am still not sure if this is due to the updates in httr/curl package or something changed with the api.